# Connect Android to Computer by Adb Tcp:Ip

Tags: android, tcp, usb, adb

i have made an app to share your monitor to your android device by wifi, it works very well.
So i wanted to put as an option to share by usb.
I have found in many websites, the adb tcp connection.
If someone could explain me.

How i can implement such thing.

What i tried so far was:
 adb forward tcp:port tcp:port
 adb connect ip

No sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the help of these [website](http://www.florescu.org/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/comment-page-2/), I understood how to Connect Tcp via Usb without using Wifi.

So what i wasn't understanding was:
º1 to connect via adb, the android device can only be the server. (otherwise it wasn't working.)
º2 you are going to connect to the localhost (i will explain it better after.) so no need of any wifi ip.

So what i did was:

1º Android: start the server to listen to any connection at PORT (Connect by Usb)
2º PC: use adb, something like: 
"shell adb.exe forward tcp:PORT tcp:PORT"
3º PC: try to connect to the server of your android device by the ip which is now "localhost" and your PORT

Then in the code i just redirected the client of the computer as an android device, and handled the server as a normal socket. (Kinda hard to explain myself.)

Answer (score 0):

Make your app run a server. Run the server on some port `e.g. port no. 5749`. Send the data thru the server then do `adb forward tcp:5749 tcp:5749  and  abd connect phoneIP`

Comment: Why would you need the phoneip when connecting trying to connect by usb, what more do i need to do, how is the tcp connection redirected ?

Comment: @Onin42 you need the phone ip because it is transmitting the data over wifi